# Transfer HTTP POST to xml with php

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file which should be contained HTTP POST request, something like:

```
<SMS>
    <MSG>HERE SHOULD BE HTTP POST REQUEST</MSG>
    <NUMER>123456789</NUMBER>
    <USERNAME>Admin</USERNAME>
<SMS>
```

How can I transfer the HTTP POST request to this specific XML file?
I don't have any background with working on XML file :\

Thank you.

Comment: Question is unclear: Are you asking how to generate an XML document from PHP, with elements name and value generated from HTTP POST parameter name and value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but you should be able to do it as simple as the following:

```
<?php
    // Your post data
    $post_msg = $_POST['message'];
    $post_number = $_POST['number'];
    $post_username = $_POST['username'];

    // Building your XML string
    $strXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'."\n";
    $strXML .= '<SMS>'."\n";
    $strXML .= '<MSG>'.$post_msg.'</MSG>'."\n";
    $strXML .= '<NUMBER>'.$post_number.'</NUMBER>'."\n";
    $strXML .= '<USERNAME>'.$post_username.'</USERNAME>'."\n";
    $strXML .= '<SMS>'."\n";

    // Print your XML
    echo $strXML;
?>
```

Save it as your_file_name.php and it should output as an XML document on the post event.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the POST keys are valid as XML tags, something like:

```
<?php
    header( 'Content-Type: text/xml' ); 
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" ?>' ;
?>
<SMS>
<?php

    foreach( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
        echo "<$key>$val</$key>\n" ; 
    }

?>
</SMS>
```